# Order result by number of occurence of a word in a text

Tags: mysql, select, sqlite, order-by

I am working with sqlite3/python .

I would like to order results by the number of occurence of `%@%` in `text`.

For exemple

```
Jimmy 10 // Jimmy wrote 10 strings like %@%
James 2
Sophia 0
..etc
```

The code could be something like this :

```
cursor = db.execute("SELECT name, text 
                       FROM MyTable
                      WHERE text LIKE '%@%'
                      ORDER BY someMagic DESC")
```

I am looking for `someMagic` if it exists :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LENGTH(text)-LENGTH(REPLACE(text,'@',''))as counting from table
ORDER BY counting DESC
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/863c89/3)